# Куда можно перенести "сохранение данных в БД" из контроллера?

Tags: symfony3

Хотелось бы уменьшить контроллер в соответствии с философией "symfony".

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use AppBundle\Entity\Users;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
...
    /**
     * @Route("/save", name="save")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     * @return Response
     */
    public function saveAction()
    {
        //возвращает массив пользователей на текущую дату
        //array(
        //    "Ivan" => 18,
        //    "Ekaterina" => 24,
        //    "Fedor" => 31,
        //);
        $users= $this->get("users")->users();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $checkNow = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('AppBundle:User')
                ->findOneBy(array("date" => $this->nowDate));

        if(null === $checkNow) {
            foreach($users as $name => $qty) {
                $userDB = new User();
                $userDB->setDate($this->nowDate);
                $userDB->setQty($qty);
                $userDB->setName($name);
                $em->persist($userDB);
            }

            $em->flush();
        }

        return new Response("save new users");
    }
```

Comment: Можете вынести все в сервис, но у меня есть вопрос, откуда в controller'е взялось свойство ```$this->nowDate```

Comment: AmsTaFFix, спасибо уже разобрался http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37855568/where-can-i-place-the-code-save-to-database-which-is-located-in-the-controlle, nowDate это DateTime(), находится выше по коду, забыл указать